# No overload for method 'form2' takes '0' arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

This is my second question for the same problem but made this example much simpler for me to understand your answers better.

I'm getting "No overload for method 'form2' takes '0' arguments"

Button on form1 takes you to form2 and also takes the value of the textbox over. Form2 displays value of textbox in label. Then I have a back button on form2 that takes you back to form1.

Im getting the error when I use the below code the second time:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Here is all the code for this example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string txtbox;

    public Form2(string txtbox)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.txtbox = txtbox;
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = txtbox;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain this and how to get this right. I'm still noob so please be detailed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have a default constructor in `Form2`, your only available constructor in `Form2` requires a string parameter.

You may define a parameterless constructor in your form.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string txtbox;
    public Form2() // a new parameterless constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The other option is to utalize the existing constructor and pass it some string value, in your button click event.

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2("somestring");// can be empty string as well
```

Comment: this line causes the problem: `Form2 frm2 = new Form2();`. Need a `string txtbox`

Answer (score 5):

Right - you've declared a constructor with a parameter:

```
public Form2(string txtbox)
```

... and there's no parameterless constructor. Note that the compiler only provides a parameterless constructor for you if you *don't* explicitly declare any constructors.

But you're trying to *call* the constructor with no arguments:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
```

What do you *want* that to do? You've basically said that in order to construct an instance of `Form2`, you *have* to provide a value for the `txtbox` parameter... but you're not doing that.

Comment: +1 - Not to mention the problems that the designer might have with this. Surely exposing a property would be a far better approach.

Answer (score 1):

this line is the culprit

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
```

Form2 does not have a constructor that takes no arguments. It has one that takes one argument (a string) so you either have to supply an argument

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2("Some string");
```

or simply create a default constructor

```
public Form2(){
   InitializeComponent();
   this.txtbox = "Deafult value";
}
```

if you need to display a text and don't have a sensible default value stick to having just one constructor. If you can supply a default value the default constructor might be a valid approach

Answer (score 1):

What its saying is that you don't have a constructor for form2 that essentially looks like this

`public Form2()
{
InitializeComponent();
}`

the values inside the () are arguments for methods

EDIT: there are two solutions to your problem..

either

```
Form2 myForm = new Form2("");
```

or

```
public Form2()
{ 
InitializeComponent();
txtBox.Text = "Defaultvalue";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code in the Form2 class is wrong

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

You need to pass a value in the constructor:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2("Some value here");
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Much like you do in Form1.

Alternatively you can overload the Form2 constructor so you can create without the value being passed in too:

```
public Form2() : this(string.Empty){}

//This is your existing constructor
public Form2(string txtbox)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.txtbox = txtbox;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All the answers have addressed why you get the error and what to do, but I think what you really want is to open **Form1** from **Form2** (as you described in the question).

I'm guessing that **Form2** button1_Click is your "Back" button.

So, in **Form2** button1_Click, change:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Show();
```

to:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.Show();
```

Result:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    /* ... */

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

---

But, to make this even better, you should probably open **Form2** as a dialog and let **Form1** take care of the result so you can reuse **Form1** instead of creating a new one every time.

Something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);

        // Hide Form1 before opening Form2.
        this.Hide();

        var dialogResult = frm2.ShowDialog(); // This method will freeze until you close Form2.

        // Then we show this form again. You can check the dialogResult if you want some logic.
        this.Show();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string txtbox;

    public Form2(string txtbox)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.txtbox = txtbox;
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = txtbox;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // Not necessary, but good if you want to have some logic.

        // Close this form (Form2) and returns to the Form1 button1_Click.
        this.Close();
    }
}
```